# including tel:// key in info.plist

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In my application, i am using the `telprompt://` scheme (and not `tel://`) if a user needs to make a call, because i want him to come back to the app screen.

But when going through the Apple's document `"iOS App Programming guide"`, i read that the user needs to include a `"telephony"` key. Here's what it says about it:

> Include this key if your app requires (or specifically prohibits) the presence of the Phone app. You might require this feature if your app opens URLs with the tel scheme.

What should i do? should i not include this key in `info.plist`? Will using this scheme become an obstacle in app approval process?

Comment: I don't think so. There is no need of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only include that key if your app can only function on an iOS device with a phone. If your use of the phone is optional, do not include the key.

Comment: my app supports iPad and iPhones. SO this means that i should include this key.. right?? so what should i write for the key??

Comment: Please read my answer again. Since your use of a phone is optional, do NOT include the `telephony` device capability key.